# Please explain the difference between two css selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I thought that there are no difference between .foo.bar  and .foo .bar //the second has space between

Answer (score 0):

`.foo.bar` refers to an element that has both classes `foo` and `bar`

while

`.foo .bar` implies that `bar` is nested in the class of `foo`

source: [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors)